# Use filter to get correct selected option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have a table like this:

```
+--------+----------+---------+
|     ID |  Nombre  | PadreID |
+--------+----------+---------+
|      1 | KENWORTH |       0 |
|      2 | VOLVO    |       0 |
|      3 | T6000    |       2 |
|      4 | T800     |       1 |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

And a select like this one:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-hide="Catalogos.length==0" ng-change="filtro(selected)"
ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos "></select>
```

I charge it using a function like:

```
  function cargarCatalogo() {
   apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoPadre/" + $scope.Catalogo + "/",
     null,
     function(res) {
       $scope.Catalogos = res.data;

       $scope.selected = $filter('filter')($scope.Catalogos, {
         ID: $scope.padreID
       }, true);

       $scope.filtro($scope.selected);
     },
     errorCatalogo);
 }
```

I want to get selected of my database for example if I click edit into `T6000` it have `PadreId = 2` so I selected should be `VOLVO` who has `ID = 2` but if I edit T800 with `PadreId = 1` selected should be KENWORTH who has `ID = 1`

How do I use correctly `filter` and then select select that option as selected?

when I console it I get right values as:

[image]

[image]

But I just can´t get as default value using `$scope.filtro($scope.selected);` can someone help me please?

**UPDATE:**

**$scope.filtro definition:**

```
  $scope.filtro = function(selected) {
                $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
            }
```

**UPDATE 2**

As Vanojx1 comment I use find function like this:

```
function cargarCatalogo() {
  apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoPadre/" + $scope.Catalogo + "/",
    null,
    function(res) {
      $scope.Catalogos = res.data;

    },
    errorCatalogo);
}
$scope.filtro = function(selected) {
  $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
}

$scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos.find(function(catalog) {
  return catalog.ID == $scope.padreID;
});

$scope.filtro($scope.selected);
```

but I´m getting `selected is undefined`, can anyone help me please?

Comment: $filter return an array, you need an item of the array in `$scope.selected` , 
try with 
 `$scope.selected = $filter('filter')($scope.Catalogos, { ID: $scope.padreID }, true)[0]`;
and you dont need to call `$scope.filtro($scope.selected);`

Comment: I try it, but I just keep getting white default first option, and I get undefined at `$scope.selected` @FetraR.

Comment: add $scope.filtro definition

Comment: I added it, please review my update @Vanojx1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$filter` function return an array and in `$scope.selected` you need an object, a [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function is enough:

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Catalogos = [{ID: 1,Nombre: "KENWORTH",PadreID: 0},{ID: 2,Nombre: "VOLVO",PadreID: 0},{ID: 3,Nombre: "T6000",PadreID: 2},{ID: 4,Nombre: "T800",PadreID: 1}];

  $scope.padreID = 2;

  $scope.filtro = function(selected) {
    $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
  }

  $scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos.find(function(catalog) {
    return catalog.ID == $scope.padreID
  });

  $scope.filtro($scope.selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <select class="form-control" ng-hide="Catalogos.length==0" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos "></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Vanojx1, I try it as your comment but I ´m gettng `selected is undefined` are you there?, I update y question with current code. Regards

Comment: I found solution, it´s quite simple just  find option need to be inside `CargarCatalogo` function. I really really appreciated your help. Thanks so much!